# Push notification with firebase ionic3

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I use [cordova-plugin-firebase] for push notification and I use firebase Realtime DataBase. I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error below.

error:« this.firebase.getToken() is not a function»

**Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {
  user: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private firebase: FirebaseProvider
  ) {
    this.auth.currentUserObservable.subscribe(() => {
      this.user = this.firebase.getUserInfo(this.auth.currentUserId);

      if (!this.auth.authenticated) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
      }
    });
    this.pushsetup();
  }
  pushsetup() {
    this.firebase
      .getToken()
      .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));
    this.firebase
      .onTokenRefresh()
      .subscribe((token: string) => console.log(`Got a new token ${token}`));
  }
}
```

**code FirebaseProvider **

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

   @Injectable()
   export class FirebaseProvider {

   constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) { }


   getUserInfo(uid){
   return this.afd.object('/users/'+ uid).valueChanges();
   }
   }
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you provide an extra code of `FirebaseProvider `?

Comment: Try this: this.firebase.getIdToken(); If this not work, try somethig like this: firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()

Answer (score 0):

`this.firebase` in the ContactPage Class is a reference to your own FirebaseProvider(-Class), not the cordova FirebaseAddon. In Your Class is no Method named `.getToken()` so the error is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

According to the : [Firebase Documentation | getToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken)

This property is deprecated. Use firebase.User#getIdToken instead.

```
this.firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((token)=>{
   console.log(`The token is ${token}`)
}).catch(function(error) {
   // Handle error
});
```

You can use **onAuthStateChanged** to validate whether user is signed in before getting the token.

```
this.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then((token)=>{
     console.log(`The token is ${token}`)
    });
  }
});
```